# estimate of maximum likelihood of $B* = (a,b)^t$

Tags: self-study, multiple-regression, estimation

The model is:

$Y_i = B_i + B_2x_i + e_i$ $i= 1, ... , 10$

$x_i = i$

$y = (8,4,4,7,8,8,4,9,4,5)$

I'm find:

$[B_1, B_2]^T = [84.77; 13.67]^T$

$s^2 = 5.20$

On the same data, adapt the following model:

$Y_i = a + e_i$
$x_i < 6 $

$Y_i = a + b(x_i-1)$
$x_i >= 6$

I must find the estimate of maximum likelihood of $B* = (a,b)^t$ of the new model $Y = X*B*$

I'm trying to solve the system but...I can't find a solution...

1. $B_i + B_2x_i = a $
2. $B_i + B_2x_i = a + b(x_i-1)$
3. $B_i + B_2x_i = a $
4. $B_i + B_2x_i = a + bx_i-b$

I don't think, I should recalculate everything from the beginning....It seems strange and anyway I already have the values ​​of B estimators...
Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: the new model replaces $x=(1,2,\ldots,10)$ by $(0,0,0,0,0,5,6,7,8,9)$.

Comment: Did you solve the equation system ?